# Mutually exclusive arguments

Tags: python

Sometimes I have functions that accept multiple ways to pass data. This is usually with exceptions, like this:

```py
class InvalidFileError(Exception):
    
    def __init__(self, filecontent: str = None, path: pathlib.Path = None):
        """
        Path and content are mutually exclusive, though this is not enforced.
        If both are provided, will default to path
        """
        self.message = None
        if path:
            self.message = f"File at path {path} is invalid"
        elif content:
            self.message = f"Invalid data:\n{content}"
        if self.message:
            super().__init__(self.message)
```

In the above code, `filecontent` and `path` are mutually exclusive.

How should I make these arguments mutually exclusive? Should I just leave a warning in the docstring and hope it is respected? Should I throw an exception if both are provided? Should I throw a warning? Should I have it default to one of the arguments?

All of these ways work. However, none of them feel right. What's the best (most pythonic) way to do this?

Comment: The API doesn't seem right. How would you _use_ this? Why not have classmethods e.g. `InvalidFileError.from_content` and `InvalidFileError.from_path`? Or at least make the arguments keyword-only to minimise ambiguity.

Comment: You should explicitly raise an error by checking if both arguments are provided, e.g., `if path is not None and filecontent is not None: raise TypeError("expected either path or filecontent but not both")`. This is how the standard library does it, and most other libraries. There isn't anything unpythonic about it

Comment: @jonrsharpe I feel like having classmethods is a lot bulkier and less convenient to use than a monolithic function. Also, I've never seen that style used in exceptions in the standard library or any codebases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard way (which can be enforced via static type checkers like `mypy`) is to use `typing.overload` to explicitly define the acceptable combinations of arguments:

```
import pathlib
from typing import overload

class InvalidFileError(Exception):

    @overload
    def __init__(self, *, content: str = None): ...

    @overload
    def __init__(self, *, path: pathlib.Path = None): ...
    
    def __init__(self, *, content: str = None, path: pathlib.Path = None):
        """
        Path and content are mutually exclusive.
        """
        if path and content:
            raise TypeError("Invalid arg combination.  Did you forget to run mypy?")

        self.message: str | None = None
        if path:
            self.message = f"File at path {path} is invalid"
        elif content:
            self.message = f"Invalid data:\n{content}"

        if self.message:
            super().__init__(self.message)
```

Running the four possible ways to call this through `mypy` we get:

```
InvalidFileError()  # ok
InvalidFileError(content="foo")  # ok
InvalidFileError(path=pathlib.Path("bar"))  # ok
InvalidFileError(content="foo", path=pathlib.Path("bar"))  # error:
# test.py:28: error: No overload variant of "InvalidFileError" matches argument types "str", "Path"
# test.py:28: note: Possible overload variants:
# test.py:28: note:     def __init__(self, *, content: Optional[str] = ...) -> InvalidFileError
# test.py:28: note:     def __init__(self, *, path: Optional[Path] = ...) -> InvalidFileError
```

A simpler option would be to forgo the complication of having them be separate keyword arguments, and just take a single positional argument with a union type:

```
class InvalidFileError(Exception):
    
    def __init__(self, path_or_content: pathlib.Path | str | None = None):
        if path_or_content is None:
            self.message: str | None = None
        elif isinstance(path_or_content, pathlib.Path):
            self.message = f"File at path {path_or_content} is invalid"
        elif isinstance(path_or_content, str):
            self.message = f"Invalid data:\n{path_or_content}"
        else:
            raise TypeError(f"{path_or_content!r} is an invalid type!")

        if self.message:
            super().__init__(self.message)


InvalidFileError()  # ok
InvalidFileError("foo")  # ok
InvalidFileError(pathlib.Path("bar"))  # ok
```

Comment: I wouldn't say this is a substition for explicity raising an error if both arguments are provided. The standard library does this and so do most libraries

Comment: Yes, doing both is ideal IMO -- have type annotations that will allow a static type checker to enforce usage, but also raise a runtime `TypeError` if usage is incorrect regardless.  At least if you're not pretty certain that everything in your codebase is strictly typed, type checking is happening in CI, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Personally, I think the second solution is a little ugly, but I like the first one.